# Upload files from blobstore to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, blobstore

I want upload a file that i have in the blobstore and i want send to a user of my aplication in Python. For this user, i have the name of account "xxx@gmail.com" and their password. How cant i make this?

I use this, but don't function:

```
    def subirArchivoDrive (self,f):
    # Create a client class which will make HTTP requests with Google Docs server.
    client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
    # Authenticate using your Google Docs email address and password.
    client.ClientLogin('admin@onohat.es', 'xxxxxxxxxx')
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45)
    ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_path=f, content_type="text/plain")
    client.UploadDocument(ms, "SERENOPROBANDO", f)
```

The error occurs in the line: ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_path=f, content_type="text/plain") and "f" is:

```
        self.fileName = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename=nombreCSV)
```

The error is:

2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
Traceback (most recent call last):
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_dist/lib/python2.5/dummy_thread.py", line 51, in start_new_thread
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
    function(*args, **kwargs)
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369704550404323662/src/exportacion.py", line 271, in principal
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
    self.subirArchivoDrive(self.fileName)
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369704550404323662/src/exportacion.py", line 343, in subirArchivoDrive
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
    ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_path=f, content_type="text/plain")
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369704550404323662/gdata/**init**.py", line 92, in **init**
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
    self.setFile(file_path, content_type)
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369704550404323662/gdata/**init**.py", line 103, in setFile
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
    self.file_handle = open(file_name, 'rb')
E 2013-08-23 13:32:24.859
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/blobstore/writable:AD8BvukgB3Fn-zPXCfo-R3MWqu0IL-WBaL6Pa1BbxTL9gGpC5mrmyRMWIbaVUYT1kPoFY1ykhe8GUVV_c1pmm7jlDRruK1UFT906QI-L6qyzgY1JASuOztZhtN3AleoU4VWIJlGNqkC9ykrToM8TaV_TqfNZEmLNDptpHrKl_IZlU_tnkfieihAizYT9ri7-fNl2LMHSMC4w9BhY3BKJs9jDnGnX91B9bqkbSty-G2sbLRAZZFo1it2nwgQxJdW9F4wqn2h9_Lg6fjka_myXLUrVWrQpc9V9sB3xX_NAY1YJ5QXDgP3cPKKg-doykPO4lIhTqRqZ2zyFUx-zRUJbcyzTMM_u9SmGGeVFMwLpTGEhuX9zA_N9_dMbPnxoV3Sd5ExkYZ1AZUbma6ZZmIJe-R2T4Htb5DbXDDtrrSojRx5Qgyio25tlP5h6sZSUrxvRT0TQK7IgjZxHSli3iagS7EEckcFe3Vp4t97BBHa-Bo0cPh3A4KZ5BFpRz0cP_dG9ntZfe7W1VBhCGZ6oyotzcFUXJUBMZal0rJ56zRIFIdIOnqbZf-PSC3RWp5F-oRbABnRnnRF4Rm3e1I1XGHWkZ2mX_kIBSoJKC8CxhZwRyInmbxcv2kqd1z53CjIW1vRH3_r0n6QhpfARqJc3vQ7Jhsxeycy_SQTuBKOfkXXTXAGdengBZ7qPi3nWZw-mCbnS9SgvoANd99X3hoUK2DfNJScWXLQ2BsPoUTO07ubNJwRJC86HRlLmNM5ToKYuRvPtmPpW9imht5uqIKpTx-2tcmArQNAHy9eYaSXzZsI5PAipl-CwgUkfGUqmU1svFvcM585X7XL3zt5P44pPUQqSsKE8GFNAxKWwSLp46p-qkxLBVvo7UwstYTja7SgX9L2cn89hptHRq4C7Rzy1u3r5i4HawvrFDeT5fSh9R-feHOqndQCS16bAFDKaknOZdSLX0iidGzyGEam_ZCMQneLm5GiXsu79q7RNUw'

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

MediaSource receives either a `file_path` or a `file_handle`. If a file_path is provided it has to be the path of a readable file in the filesystem. Alternatively you can provide a file like object (an opened file) as the `file_handle`. See the [documentation](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.html#MediaSource) or the  [source](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/__init__.py#64).

[blobstore.create](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore) is a function that creates a filename that can be opened for writing only with the blobstore service and is in fact deprecated.

If you already have the file in blobstore, you need to use [BlobInfo.open](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass#BlobInfo_open) instead. 
`ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_handle=blobinfo.open(), content_type="text/plain")`.

Also, I hope that the pasted password is not a real one. Note as well that asking the user for her password is not a good practice and you should use OAuth instead.

Note as well that some gdata apis has been replaced for more modern versions, in this case by the [Drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/). Look at this [complete python example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python).